# Facebook Javascript SDK window location reload not working on Firefox

Tags: firefox, window, location, reload, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm building a website with Facebook Connect and therefore using the Facebook Javascript SDK. 
**Problem:** when using Firefox, the page doesn't reload properly once logged in or logged out.

```
FB.Event.subscribe(
   '{% if current_user %}auth.logout{% else %}auth.login{% endif %}',
    function(response){
        window.location.reload();
});
```

Obviously, it looks like a known problem (just type "window location reload not working on firefox" and you'll get a lot of results)

More precisely, Firefox doesn't seem to send the right cookie when reloading the page... 
 - When I click to login, once Facebook logged me in and sets a cookie, Firefox doesn't send any cookie
 - When I click to logout, once Facebook has logged me out and remove the cookie, Firefox sends the cookie that was previously there.
**I conclude it uses some "cache functions".**

I tried to make a workaround as described [here](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=108498) and implemented this:

```
redirect_url = encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
url = window.location.href + "account/login?redirect_url=" + redirect_url;
window.location.replace(url);
```

But the problem remains (the cache I guess...) Can you help me out with this?

Thanks.

Comment: `window.location.reload(true);`  helps ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try wrapping the window.location.reload() call in a setTimeout() with a zero delay. Apparently, Firefox fires the event before setting the cookie. The wrapping should place the reload call in the event queue and allow the cookies to be set correctly.

Comment: TADAAA!! Thanks a lot. It both solved my problem with Firefox and Safari (I just figured out that it used to cause an infinite loop in Safari...)

Comment: Hmmm, interesting!! Mind extending your answer (add some resources..etc)?

Comment: There is a bunch of bug reports related to the underlying issue in Bugzilla, e.g., http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=20499, http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=20061 Just search for "event login"

Comment: If you're not sure what the wrapping means, see the Chad's post below.

Comment: hi @chwk I have this problem too, but the settimeout is not preventing from happend on ie, I even tried adding more time than 0 nothing seems to work :S any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Incase there was anymore confusion over this, for Firefox, the above referenced example of `setTimeout()` works perfectly. Simply include your reload call, or if it's easier just replace:

```
document.location.reload();
```

with:

```
setTimeout('document.location.reload()',0);
```

Using the most recent version of Firefox released, I have tested every example above, and this is the only one that has actually worked consistently. Basically, you just need to "pause" the JavaScript just for a moment to let the rest of the script catch up. I did not test this on Chrome or IE, but it does work flawlessly on Firefox.

Comment: thx for the clearer explanation, I wasn't sure what the "wrapping" exactly means.

Answer (score 0):

We are using the work-around with

```
window.location.href = url;
```

instead of

```
window.location.replace(url);
```

Works fine in Firefox, too.

Comment: Sorry but it does not work for me on Firefox (on MAC by the way). The FB cookie is not sent to this "login url". I still need to do a manual refresh after that...

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using Rails and Koala, you can just check for the cookies and redirect to the same action if they are not present:

```
def fb_authenticate
  @fb_cookies ||= Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new.get_user_info_from_cookie(cookies)
  if @fb_cookies
    #login user or create new user
  else
    redirect_to :controller => 'account', :action => 'fb_authenticate'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try redirect to a different URL each time:

```
top.location.href = 'https://apps.facebook.com/YOUR_APP_NAME/?t=' + <?php echo time(); ?>;
```

, I use PHP but you can replace with JS ( Math.round(+new Date()/1000) I guess ).