# JS SDK auth.logout event behavior seems to have changed recently - what is going on?

Tags: javascript, sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk, logout

I have been using the below code in combination with the the JS SDK for several months. Over the past few days it's been giving me all sorts of issues.

1. Logout Event doesn't fire on logout - I'm using JS XFBML Tag for login/out, as in:

Note: clicking the logout button does logout from FB but the event does not fire on my site.

1. The logout event does fire when I reload the page when logged out, which causes a page re-loading loop when logout event fires.  Not that big of a deal right now since the initial logout event doesn't fire.  However before today, the logout event fired on logout and on every page load (when logged-out) meaning that it would endlessly reload the page via logout redirect.

This all worked fine until a few days ago and I haven't touched that part of code in several weeks or months. Any thoughts?

Event Code:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {

    window.location.href = '/logout.php';

    });
```

Note: I am also using the php SDK for other functionality on the site - I'm using the latest versions of both

I found another post on here about this issue, but the solution is to just remove the reload, which is a terrible solution - why is this JS Event working this way?

Thanks!

Comment: I am having similiar difficulties, did you make any progress?

Comment: My solution was to simply remove the the FB logout functions from the site.  I figure people don't really want to logout of FB from my site anyway (and maybe that's what FB is thinking too) - so instead I just allow a direct logout of my site that doesn't touch FB credentials. The one thing I would like to have is the logout event fire on user logout via FB so that I know that they aren't fully logged-in to my site - it uses a lot of ajax so the user doesn't load new pages that often and a lot of the functionality is broken if FB connection is not present, so now I must check status

Answer (score 0):

Well, I came up with a workaround, though I am not proudy of it at all. I am using these events:

```
 FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
    setTimeout('document.location.reload()',0);
 });
 FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
    <? if ($_SESSION['user']['id']): unset($_SESSION['user']); ?>
    setTimeout('document.location.reload()',0);
    <? endif; ?>
 });
```

I store all user information in session and the condition concerning SESSION makes sure the page doesn't end up in a loop. The setTimeout is used because of [Facebook Javascript SDK window location reload not working on Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553037/facebook-javascript-sdk-window-location-reload-not-working-on-firefox) .
Than I added a jQuery function to reload the page after the logoutButton is clicked:

```
$(function() {
    $('#logoutButton').click(function() {
        setTimeout('document.location.reload()',0);
    });
});

<span id="<?= $user ? "logout" : "login" ?>Button">
    <fb:login-button autologoutlink="true"></fb:login-button>
</span>
```

I've tested this on Firefox and Chrome and worked fine. This is not real solution it's more like ugly fix :), but I decided to post it anyway. I am thinking now actually to leave the whole "logging out operation", because most of the users don't want be logged out from Facebook anyway.

Comment: " I am thinking now actually to leave the whole "logging out operation", because most of the users don't want be logged out from Facebook anyway."   Yes, that's exactly the position I came to :)