# redirection cookie stuck in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

For some reason this script gets stuck in a redirection loop and wont let you leave "android.html". The url bar shows it is trying to go to "index.html" but it just flashes then stays on "android.html"

```
    var caution = false

function setCookie(name, value, expires, path, domain, secure) {
    var curCookie = name + "=" + escape(value) +
            ((expires) ? "; expires=" + expires.toGMTString() : "") +
            ((path) ? "; path=" + path : "") +
            ((domain) ? "; domain=" + domain : "") +
            ((secure) ? "; secure" : "")
    if (!caution || (name + "=" + escape(value)).length <= 4000)
            document.cookie = curCookie
    else
            if (confirm("Cookie exceeds 4KB and will be cut!"))
                    document.cookie = curCookie
}

function getCookie(name) {
    var prefix = name + "="
    var cookieStartIndex = document.cookie.indexOf(prefix)
    if (cookieStartIndex == -1)
            return null
    var cookieEndIndex = document.cookie.indexOf(";", cookieStartIndex + prefix.length)
    if (cookieEndIndex == -1)
            cookieEndIndex = document.cookie.length
    return unescape(document.cookie.substring(cookieStartIndex + prefix.length,     cookieEndIndex))
}

function deleteCookie(name, path, domain) {
    if (getCookie(name)) {
            document.cookie = name + "=" + 
            ((path) ? "; path=" + path : "") +
            ((domain) ? "; domain=" + domain : "") +
            "; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT"
    }
}

function fixDate(date) {
    var base = new Date(0)
    var skew = base.getTime()
    if (skew > 0)
            date.setTime(date.getTime() - skew)
}

var now = new Date()
fixDate(now)
now.setTime(now.getTime() + 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
var visits = getCookie("indexVisited")
if (!visits)
window.location.replace("./android.html");
else 
window.location.replace("./index.html");
setCookie("indexVisited", visits, now)
```

Comment: missing a whole lot of semicolons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides missing a whole lot of semicolons, your code tries to set the cookie after it redirects to another page. Javascript stops executing upon a redirect, so your `setCookie` call never gets executed. Try moving it up before the redirects.

Comment: what line should I move my setCookie before?

Comment: you may find something useful in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553037/facebook-javascript-sdk-window-location-reload-not-working-on-firefox