# Facebook infinite loop, setTimeout not helping =(

Tags: javascript, facebook, oauth, reload, infinite-loop

I have a loop on my facebook when using ie and firefox ([Facebook Javascript SDK window location reload not working on Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553037/facebook-javascript-sdk-window-location-reload-not-working-on-firefox))
because of the:

```
FB.Event.suscribe('auth.login',function(response){
    location.reload(true);
});
```

I tryied with:

```
FB.Event.suscribe('auth.login',function(response){
    window.setTimeout('location.reload(true)',0);
});
```

But it keeps doing the loop.

Additional information: I'm only using html,javascript and jquery not using php, asp, aspx, ruby, nothing else than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to:

```
FB.Event.suscribe('auth.login',function(response){
   window.setTimeout(function () {
       location.reload(true);
   },0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call reload if user already connected

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    var reload = function(){location.reload(true);};
    if(response.status !== 'connected'){
        FB.Event.subcribe('auth.login',function(response){
            setTimeout(reload,0);
        });
    }else {
        FB.Event.subcribe('auth.logout',function(response){
            setTimeout(reload,0);
        });
    }
});
```